# Why did we assign Font.PLAIN to an int value like valBold here? are fonts in java integers?

Tags: java, event-handling

```
  public class CheckBoxHandler implements ItemListener {
        private int valBold = Font.PLAIN;
        private int valItalic = Font.PLAIN;

        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

            if(e.getSource() == boldCheckBox)
                valBold = boldCheckBox.isSelected() ? Font.BOLD : Font.PLAIN;

            if(e.getSource() == italicCheckBox)
                valItalic = italicCheckBox.isSelected() ? Font.ITALIC : Font.PLAIN;

            textField.setFont(new Font("Serif", valBold + valItalic, 14));
        }
    }//End inner class
```

I tried assigning Font.PLAIN to some other datatypes than integers and I was only allowed to use double and float, and I didn't get why does the compiler consider fonts numeral types.

Answer (score 0):

It does not "consider fonts numeral types". If I write `int fruit = 7` the compiler does not "consider all fruits to be numeral types". That is simply not how compilers work.

`Font.PLAIN` is defined to be an `int`, more precisely a `public static final int PLAIN`. The fact that it's name suggests anything else does not matter to the compiler, and neither should it.